# Blockchain and Bitcoin client difference of amount

Tags: transactions, blockchain, multibit

I just made a transfer of 0.06 BTC, you can look it up on [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx-index/005dcacae99b2e50d3deac9d8c0fd0e903a9cfbd9fefd9ebf3dc28eb3d6fe69a)

The problem now is that my receiving client (Multibit) doesn't show those 0.06 BTC, it only shows 0.0001 BTC have been spend (most probably as mining fee).

[image: Transaction details of the receiving client]

The 'view at blockchain.info' button takes me to the same Blockchain page as mentioned in the beginning. How should i understand this, and where did my 0.06 BTC go?

Comment: Doesn't your client show right in the "Raw Transaction" field "to 1BnAtNAYwhLt4kCAqUPG1F7FoHh4mmSTHQ 0.06 BTC"? Is that your own address perhaps?

Comment: Both are my own addresses. The source is a Blockchain-wallet, and the destination is a MultiBit-wallet

Answer (score 1):

You've probably sent TO an address in your wallet. The amount is shown as a net figure. I.e.it is a bit like you have transfered money from your left pocket to your right pocket. MultiBit just shows the fee that you have sent to the miner.

Comment: I thought so too but then i didn't see the same amount being add up somewhere else. So i am not trying to figure out where the 0.0599 BTC (0.06-0.0001) are.